# Extracting text between a certain range

Tags: r, regex

I've been struggling coming up with a solution to extracting the text from this PDF document that I'm processing.

The text looks like this:

```
"* text text text\n text text text.\n      * text text text text text text.\n"
```

I'm trying to end up with the following, as separate values in a vector:

```
"* text text text\n text text text." 
"* text text text text text text."
```

I can't run a delimiter on `\n`, and when I try running a delimiter all the way up to the nearest bullet, it fails. As I understand it, I need to limit the range between two bullets and need to create the length at the last `\n` and I'm just not sure how to do that.

This is the regex query I have right now:

```
"\\* (.)*\n"
```

Comment: Are `\n` literal or are they newline characters?

Comment: They're new line characters, but it's a text document, so I assume that it treats them the same.

Comment: Split on `\s+(?=\*)`

Comment: Try `strsplit(x, "\\.\\n")` then `trimws`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `strsplit`:

```
string = "* text text text\n text text text.\n      * text text text text text text.\n"

unlist(strsplit(string, "\n(\\s{2,}|$)"))
# [1] "* text text text\n text text text." "* text text text text text text."
```

Another option is to use `str_extract` from `stringr` wrapping the regex with `regex` and utilizing the `dotall` option:

```
library(stringr)

unlist(str_extract_all(string, regex("\\*.+?\\.", dotall = TRUE)))
# [1] "* text text text\n text text text." "* text text text text text text."
```

**Note:**

- With `dotall=TRUE`, `.` will now also match `\n`.
- `?` in `.+?` enables lazy matching